# Display votes on the question

Tags: feature-request

It would be good to be able to see which question you have voted and not vote  and how many answers you have voted and not vote by glancing over the questions list of question on the front page. There is not visual or other indication of this at the moment.

Comment: Sounds like a feature request to the Stack Exchange development team.

Comment: Yes. This way you can know questions you have vote and out of the answers how may you have voted on.

Comment: Yes, this isn't the right place to post these suggestions. You should try http://meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Echoing Andrei and yuttadhammo - feel free to expand on this request with examples or mockups and post it on meta.stackexchange.com. The community there will vet it and help you flesh it out. It's the best place for it to get seen by enough people to give it momentum to get built.

Answer (score 1):

Further to the comments above, I suggest you look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed?sort=newest to see what requests StackExchange have been "completing" recently.

That will illustrate by example what kind of detail they like to see in a request.

Note that most of what has been completed (or accepted for development) recently has been 'bug' not 'feature-request' items.

There have been nearly 18,000 feature requests: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request

Comment: 18k backlog means this might get lost in all the requests.

Comment: Imagine what the UI would be like if there were all implemented! Can you rephrase your 'feature-request' as a 'bug' instead, as something which diminishes the user experience? Perhaps they would be more likely to fix a bug.

Comment: Yes it's a bug. You have to open each question to know what questions and answers you have not voted for.