# Could we be able to choose more than one answer to our questions with a check-mark?

Tags: support, feature-request

I appreciate that there is the option to up-vote answers, but I would also like to be able to choose more than one answer as the "this helped me most". I realize that the idea of "most" would not be honoured in the strict sense that governs competition, but in this context... maybe we could move beyond it ?

if the concern is that it should be done sparingly, perhaps there can be a "cost" to the "asker".

In some situations where I ask a group of people to vote for something I do not give them one vote each, but rather 5 votes each. I tell them they can allot the votes as a block, or in pieces. This results in a clearer picture when I add up the votes. It also leads to people having a higher sense of ownership in the final outcome.

thank you for considering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current software doesn't permit it, so that would be a new feature request.

I don't know whether Stack Exchange developers or product managers read this Meta site, or whether you must post any feature-request on the main http://meta.stackexchange.com site instead.

Beware that I fear that, no matter how good your suggestion is, I think it's unlikely to be accepted for implementation -- see for example my answers to previous feature-request topics:

- https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2082/254
- https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/314/254
- https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1845/254

Comment: Let me know if you would be helped by my posting it on the main page. thank you for your (extra-ordinarily prompt! and detailed) reply soft smile - je viens de réaliser que nous sommes deux francophones qui se parlent en anglais ;) c'est comique ! - bonne journée..

Comment: De rien ! :-) En fait je suis anglophone, mais mon école primaire était en français et il me semble que ça se voit dans quelques de mes phrases écrites (p. ex. "I fear that" -> "Je crains que").

Comment: Je suis francophone, mais j’ai fait toute mon éducation en anglais...  alors... nous sommes les deux côtés de la même médaille. Tu écris très bien en anglais... et l’anglais, langue qui est faite de pièces volées et recycler, pardonne... n’hésite pas...  ton discours est plus important que ton manteau.